# Command Not Found error when calling monetdb.server.start in R

Tags: r, monetdb

I am trying to replicate CMS publications and require the use of `MonetDB` to do so, but am having trouble starting the server. I set up the server as follows:

```
library(R.utils)
library(MonetDB.R)
batfile <-
monetdb.server.setup(
                database.directory = paste0( getwd() , "/MonetDB" ) ,
                monetdb.program.path = 
                    ifelse( 
                        .Platform$OS.type == "windows" , 
                        "C:/Program Files/MonetDB/MonetDB5" , 
                        "" 
                    ) ,
                dbname = "bsapuf" ,
                dbport = 50003
)
```

The error occurs when I try to startup the server using the following code:

```
pid <- monetdb.server.start( batfile )
```

And is as follows:

```
/Users/ktrahair/Documents/2.1_AEUM_CLASS/Final_Project/MonetDB/bsapuf.sh: line   2: mserver5: command not found
Read 1 item
```

The content of the text file that is being accessed is:

```
#!/bin/sh

mserver5 --set prefix= --set exec_prefix= --dbpath /Users/ktrahair/Documents/2.1_AEUM_CLASS/Final_Project/MonetDB/bsapuf --set mapi_port=50003 --daemon yes > /dev/null &

echo $! > /Users/ktrahair/Documents/2.1_AEUM_CLASS/Final_Project/MonetDB/mserver5.started.from.R.pid
```

This is my first time using StackOverflow, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Kyle

Comment: And the complete error message is ... ?

Comment: Offhand I would guess that you are copying the code from someone who is on Windoze and that you are on a Mac. Seems more likely to succeed if you use `monetdb.program.path="/usr/local/monetdb/"`. You should tell us how you installed your copy of MonetDB. If this isn't sounding familiar, then please look at the DESCRIPTION file linked from the package help Index display by:  `help(pack=MonetDB.R)`

Comment: I installed my copy of MonetDB using macports. The initial error report I was getting was: `mserver5: command not found`. When I include the path information the error I get is:  `/mserver5: No such file or directory`

Comment: Macports installs its external packages in a particular directory. (I forget which one). Use locate monetdb in a Terminal session to find your copy. You were telling the system to look for your copy of MonetDB in paste0("","/MonetDB") and there's no there there.

Comment: what happens when you run the example in `?monetdb.server.setup`